# Two users associated with the same record?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, relationship

In my Rails application I have a `Prescription` model. Currently each `Prescription` belongs to a `User` and each `User` can have multiple `Prescriptions`.

The `Prescription` is owned by the `User` that created the `Prescription`, however, I would now like to also associate the `Prescription` to a vet (another `User`).

Is this possible?

I considered adding a column to `Prescription` called `vet_id` and somehow linking that to the `User` table.

At the moment the `Prescription` table has a column called `user_id` and a column called `vet`. The `vet` column is simple a manually typed name followed by the vets qualifications. I would like to pull in the vets name followed by their qualifications, but also I would like to automatically display a list of vets on the new prescription form. This would only be possible if I could iterate through the users with a department that matched `vet`.

Any pointers would be appreciated. The Rails application is on v3.2 and the database is MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `vet_id` to your `Prescription` table sounds good to me.  If there are special attributes you want to maintain or report for "vets", you might want to create a separate `vets` table.  On the other hand, you might only need to define a new column in your `users` table (perhaps `is_a_vet`) to identify these people.  A query for either solution can provide a selection list of "vets" for your application.

Comment: If I add `vet_id`, it would just contain the `user_id`. Any idea how I would link that to a `user`?

Comment: Could you not identify these people by having some form of roles? Also @BellevueBob when you suggested to have `is_a_vet` do you mean that he could add this into his table as a boolean value and set this true or false which would determine if that user `is_a_vet`

Comment: @David Yes, adding an indicator to the `users` table is what I had in mind (true/false, 1/0, Y/N, or whatever is easiest for the OP).

Comment: @dannymcc To "link" the `vet_id`, you can use a foreign-key constraint on the column you add to the `Prescription` table, referring either to the `user` table or to a new table you create with all the vets.

Comment: Ok, so something like this in the Prescription model? 'belongs_to :vet, :class_name => "user", :foreign_key => 'user_id''

Comment: Could I then simply call Prescription.vet.name from within the Prescription views?